# couchbase Index not getting picked by n1ql

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I am trying to create a covering index where data is sorted by an element . 
The index doesn’t seem to be working . 
Can You please help with this

Example query –

select ax, by, az ,ts
from test 
where  meta().id like 'CX%' and az = 'BBD' 
limit 100

Example index – 
CREATE INDEX `index_test_sec_idx` ON test(ax, by, az ,ts DESC) WHERE ((meta().`id`) like "CX%") WITH { "num_replica":1 }

I am getting the below error -

No index available on keyspace csrt_test that matches your query. Use CREATE INDEX or CREATE PRIMARY INDEX to create an index, or check that your expected index is online.",

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couchbase index doesn't index document when leading index key value is MISSING.
So due to that query predicate must have reference to to leading index key to qualify the index.

```
select ax, by, az ,ts 
from test 
where meta().id like 'CX%' and az = 'BBD' AND ax IS NOT MISSING
limit 100
```

OR

```
select ax, by, az ,ts 
from test 
where meta().id like 'CX%' and az = 'BBD' 
limit 100

CREATE INDEX index_test_sec_idx ON test(az, by, ax ,ts DESC) 
WHERE ((meta().id) like "CX%")
```